# URL address of object created on dependent collection

Tags: rest, url

we are creating some REST API documentation. There are locations which blow to company. So we have created an action at the following path:

```
/company/{companyId}/locations
```

For me it is logical and i think it's in accordance with REST to GET at:

```
/company/{companyId}/locations/{locationID}
```

It should return an instance of the location, because I have created it there.

But my backend programmer insisted that it's not convenient because he must get the company object on every call. He says that I should do GET, PUT and DELETE actions at the following:

```
/locations/{locationID}
```

How to convince him that it's a good idea to have URL cohesion?

Comment: What do you mean by "which blow to company?"

Comment: This is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your programmer is right, you should add hyperlinks to the responses rather than building nested URI structures which are meaningless to the clients. Read more about HATEOAS and uniform interface constraint.